# Android List View load more items when scroll to bottom and add footer loading view

Tags: android, json, rest, listview, android-volley

I am using list view with custom rows each item has two images and some text field.

When user scroll to bottom:

- I want to load more data from my web-service .
- Add a loader in list view footer.

Currently i am doing it in this way

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            if (postAdapter == null)
                return;
            if (postAdapter.getCount() == 0)
                return;
            int l = visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItem;
            if (l >= totalItemCount && !refreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                 listView.addFooterView(footer);
                 dataIfInternet(0);
            }
        }
```

What it do:
When user scroll to bottom and as a part of last item comes visible

- it start loading data.
- Add footer view.

But there is some problems i don't want these :

- It keep doing until the last item is visible.
- since adding and removing footer view call notifyDataSetChanged() which reset list data and make images blink by setting them again and again.

[image: images blinking]

I need help to solve these issues:

- overcome to images blink on reset. And somehow reset data without blink.
- Not load data when last item is little visible, instead of this i want to reload data when scroll at last y-axis point, when no area remains to scroll (not even 1 pixel).

Comment: Please post your Adapter and class